# Regular expression: How to exclude unwanted matches

Tags: regex

I have regular expression that search for rows containing 4 digit numbers, specific 19xx.
It gives too many matches so I am looking for a way to exclude the things I dont want.

This is my current regex:

```
^\s*[^\/].*19\d{2}
```

Here are some example rows:

```
short param1 = 1994;
       short param2 = 1918;
// 1998-08-20     
       // 1998-08-20    
      //## begin protected section initialization list [51935568]
//## begin protected section initialization list [51935568]
```

*(Row 2, 4 and 5 have spaces in the beginning.)*

My regex manage to correctly:

- find row 1, 2
- exclude row 3, 6

But incorrectly also matches row 4 & 5.
I cant find a way to make te regex exlude these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to match numbers that are commented out, they are preceded with `//`:

```
^(?!\s*\/\/).*?\b(\d{4})\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/ZpYSTA/1)

---

- `^` - match beginning of string
- `(?!\s*\/\/)` - don't continue matching if `//` is found at the beginning
- `.*?\b(\d{4})\b` - match 4-digit number (with word boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to use word boundaries here:

```
\b19[0-9]{2}\b
```

The above pattern will only match `19xx` years appearing as standalone words.

### Demo